# Child routes are not detected in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am working on an ionic app (Ionic 5) and it seems like I cannot get the routes to behave correctly. Here is my app routes.

[image]

But it seems I cannot make this url working /state/test-centers

Angular does not find that route.. Here is the trace

[image]

I was just trying this.. I have tried with this as well.. Did not work either..

```
{
    path: "state",
    component: StateComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
    children: [
      { path: "test-centers", component: TestCentersComponent, pathMatch: "full" }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Is small refactoring in route structure ok?

Comment: Hi @GytisTenovimas Please do let me know what you want to do me. In my earlier apps I used to create modules when a route has multiple child pages, but as this app is much simpler, so I did not want to create modules. Do I must create modules to make the child roots working properly?

Comment: See my answer below. I think the main problem is with `pathMatch: 'full'` here because you add more than just `/state` in your URL.

Comment: Why are you using children for children, the first children inside it, define path:'test-centers'  with its component, which means the second children of object 2 should be replaced with first children of object one instead of duplicate..

Comment: Did that @MostafaHarb, did not work either.. I have edited my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `pathMatch` strategy, your routing should be like that

```
{
  path: "state",
  component: StateComponent,
   children: [
   path: "",
   component: StateComponent,
    children: [
     {path: "test-centers" , component:TestCentersComponent}
   ]
 ] 
}
```

Comment: I tried this... But in this case the state component is loaded instead of the testceter.. As long as I know Angular's default url matching technique is prefix.. so as soon as it gets state in url, it uses that instead looking further.

Comment: you're talking right but angular matches all route segments so it doesn't stop at first match if there're another segments in url , this url may help
https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Tested scenario:

```
{
    path: 'state',
    component: StateComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'centers',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: TestCentersComponent,
      },
    ],
},
```

Additionally, you need to add this to your StateComponent:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Small changes in your route. I think `pathMatch: 'full'` is not needed because it matches a whole route but you add `/test-centers` is which is not matched.

Additionally, if you don't plan to add more first-level children, then I think second-level child  can be moved to first-level since you only add `path: ''` which doesn't do much.

Comment: I did that, but if I don't specify full match, it loads the state component instead.. what a pain!! :( I think angular's default matching technique is prefix, so whenever it sees state/centers, it matches the "state" path and loads that component.. I am going mad..

Comment: What do you mean? What URL you're trying to access, what you get and what do you expect to get?

Comment: I have two components, State and TestCenters, When I access http://localhost:8100/state => It gives me the State component, And when I access http://localhost:8100/state/test-centers => It also load the Statement component. I expect to load the TestCener component instead.

Comment: Okey, I might know the issue. Check my updated answer. I think you didn't add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your StateComponent.

Comment: I did not want to add centers component within state component. I wanted to update the whole viewport (It is basically a page in ionic). So I wanted it to be pushed in the root router-outlet. Anyways, I left hope and instead of defining children, I am just defining all the routes in root level...

Comment: Then it's not working quite like you think it is. All parent components will be displayed. If you want to show only one component, then it cannot be as a child unless parent component has only `<router-outlet>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `TestCentersComponent` content displayed as a child of `StateComponent` then include `<router-outlet>` within the template of the `StateComponent` and use the following route definition. You can access this with url `/state/test-centers` and you will see the parent component rendered along with the child component template in place of the outlet.

```js
{
  path: 'state',
  component: StateComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'test-centers', component: TestCentersComponent },
  ]
}
```

Another way is with a third component, `StateContainerComponent`, acting as a container/page/layout placeholder that has nothing other than a `<router-outlet>` within it. This approach will render either the `StateComponent` or `TestCentersComponent` but not both as a parent-child render like the above method. It can also be accessed with the url `/state/test-centers`.

```js
{
  path: 'state',
  component: StateContainerComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'test-centers', component: TestCentersComponent },
    { path: '', component: StateComponent },
  ]
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdrqvg) showcasing both approaches, noting that for the latter I used the route `state-container` just for demonstrative purposes.